# Finding which values in a list are smaller/greater than a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

I've seen topics similar to this, but after trying out their methods it still didn't fix the part from **if** till the end. From what I read on other topics, the values are mismatched, yet I've been trying to fix it and trying out other methods with no success. Thank you for your help in advance.
Here's my code:

```
numbers = []

def calc():

    d=0
    m=0
    single_number=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    number = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
    numbers = [int(i) for i in number.split()]
    summed =sum(numbers, 0)/len(numbers)
    print("Average: ", summed)
    minimum=min(numbers)
    maximum=max(numbers)
    print("Minimum", minimum)
    print("Maximum", maximum)
    if numbers > single_number:
        d=d+1
    else:
        m=m+1
    print("Amount of numbers in the list that are smaller than the 1st entered number:", m)
    print("Amount of numbers in the list that are bigger than the 1st number:", d)
print(calc())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you are missing is a loop:

```
for number in numbers: 
    if numbers > single_number:
        d=d+1
    else: # elif numbers < single_number: # what if numbers == single_number?
        m=m+1
```

there are improvements you could make though. `d = d+1` is correct; i prefer `d += 1` though.

then (if you don't mind looping over your list twice):

```
d = sum(1 for number in numbers if number > single_number)
m = sum(1 for number in numbers if number < single_number)
```

would give you `d` and `m` in a compact way.

Comment: Thank you for your time answering. d = sum(1 for number in numbers if number > single_number)
m = sum(1 for number in numbers if number < single_number) is a more compact way, and I have not thought of it. it is the same as a normal for loop right? (I wanted to make a new line by pressing enter and it posted my asnwer before I could finish it, sorry about that)

Comment: yes, the `for` tells you that i t is a loop. unfortunately you loop twice over the same list where once would be enough...

Answer (score 0):

`if numbers > single_number` is doing something like:

```
if [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] > 4
```

That doesn't make any sense. Do you want a `for` loop?

```
for number in numbers:
    if number > single_number:
        d += 1
    elif number < single_number:
        m += 1
    # else doesn't make sense here, since 4 is neither larger _nor_ smaller than 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to filter and then get the length of the resulting list:

```
d = len([n for n in numbers if n > single_number])
m = len(numbers) - d
```